Cannot connect to the secondary instance in AG when adding a new database
I have an always on availability group setup with 2 instances, primary and secondary. When I try to add a new database to the AG I cannot connect to the secondary instance. This is probably due to the custom port I use on both instances. Let me show it with pictures:

When I try to connect like this, I can't and get timeout 30 seconds later. I can't connect to the secondary for I can't edit the server name. In order to connect to the other server I need to also specify the port. Same thing happens when I try to fail the AG to the secondary node. In short, anytime I need to connect to the other instance.
However, I can connect to the secondary instance if I change the 'Connect to database' from default to master in Connection Properties:

Still, the problem is when the AG is on the second server, 'Connect to database' option does not list any dbs from the primary server. I can't make any sense of this. Does anyone have a solution?
